# d3js: d3.csv and it's data disappears

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

I use this code:

```
var map_json; // in global scope
var map;
...
function get_data() {
   map_json = d3.json("data/russia_1e_7sr.json", function (e, d) {
      map = d;
   });
   // ... draw map
}
```

If I debug this code then I see the result.
If I close debugger and then refresh the page, the results disappears.

I suggest that something happening with object's memory.
But what?

What is the right way to get data with d3?
Yes, I see an examples such this:

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function(e,d) {
   // ... use d
   // all things processed inside this function
}
```

What if I want to load several data parts from different sources?

Comment: This is an async `callback` function, which means that it doesn't fire in linear sequence with the rest of the program. As a result, your drawing code fires before the file is loaded. You should invoke a function to draw the map from within the callback for linear flow. For loading multiple sources, you can either nest the loads (load in the callback of another), or define a counter which you increment with each callback and when it equals the number of data parts you call the final function.

Comment: I'm just started with js. Thanks for the good explanation: I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the draw map bit:

```
var map_json; // in global scope

...
function get_data() {
   map_json = d3.json("data/russia_1e_7sr.json", function (e, d) {
       var map;= d;
       // ... draw map
   });
}
```

`map` won't be populated yet where you have it.